# two separate login systems for hosted blazor wasm app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to have two separate login systems for a hosted blazor wasm app? The app I am working on is using azure AD for internal users and using custom jwt authentication for external users. Unfortunately they have only both worked mutually exclusively, so if I got the login system to work for internal users, then the external one won't work. And vice versa as well. How can I get them both to work for my app? Here's my program.cs in the Client folder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using mipswebapp.Client; using Blazored.Modal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Blazored.SessionStorage;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddBlazoredModal();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

// builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("my_server", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
.CreateClient("my_server"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
 
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options => {         
 builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", 
 options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
     options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("placeholder_text"); 
 options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage"; 
 options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

It seems that the azure AD would only work if I include the two lines:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("my_server", client =>
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
.CreateClient("my_server"));
```

But custom jwt only works if I comment the above two lines out and uncomment this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

Comment: I don't think you can [someone may prove we wrong].  How do you authentication against your API (if you have one)?  My guess is you need to structure your code into libraries and ensure clear segregation and abstraction between your authentication and authorization.   Then build out two deployment endpoints, one for each authentication system.

Comment: ikr it's tricky for sure. The <AuthorizeView> tag seems to only work with azure AD auth and the custom jwt auth. The conflict seems to be in program.cs and I couldn't get httpclient and httpclientfactory to coexist. I tried to use httpclientfactory for external login system and get a TokenAccessException.